# Calling ajax in callback of ajax using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

Assuming first Ajax call will succeed (yes, it is succeed).

I am calling ajax in that callback like below

```
function OnSuccess(data) {

                    $('.modal-footer').show();
                    if (data.d[4].toLowerCase().indexOf("success") >= 0) {
                        $('#resetMsg').html('Password has been sent on ' + data.d[3]);
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: "frmLogin.aspx/SendMail",
                            data: '{"mailTo":"' + data.d[3] + '","reqName":"' + data.d[0] + '","username":"' + $('#txtUser').val() + '","password":"' + data.d[2] + '"}',
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json"
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#resetMsg').html(data.d[4]);
                    }
                }
```

My `WebMethod` is

```
[WebMethod]
    static void SendMail(string mailTo, string reqName, string username, string password)
    {
        CommonClient commonSvc = new CommonClient();
        bool mailStatus = false;
        if (mailTo != string.Empty)
        {
            bool isValid = CommonUtility.isValidEmail(mailTo);
            if (!isValid)
            {
                mailStatus = false;
            }
        }
        string From = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FromEmailID"];
        string Subject = "LEAP - password reset";
        StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();
        body.Append("Password reset successfully for " + reqName +"<br>");
        body.Append("Username: " + username + "<br>");
        body.Append("Password: " + password + "<br>");
        string ErrorMsg = "";
        try
        {
            MailAddress from = new MailAddress(From, "HDFCERGO");
            MailMessage Mail = new MailMessage();
            Mail.To.Add(mailTo);
            Mail.From = from;
            Mail.Subject = Subject;
            Mail.Body = body.ToString();
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BCCEmailID"].ToString()))
            {
                Mail.Bcc.Add(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BCCEmailID"].ToString());
            }
            Mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

            SmtpClient smtpMailObj = new SmtpClient();
            smtpMailObj.Send(Mail);
            Mail.Dispose();
            mailStatus = true;
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            ErrorMsg = Ex.Message;
            mailStatus = false;
        }
        finally
        {
            LogMailSentDetails(body.ToString(), Subject, mailTo, From, mailStatus == true ? "Success" : "Failed", ErrorMsg);
        }
```

but it never get called.. :( is it because I am not passing parameters properly? please help me with that :(

Comment: Does any part of OnSuccess() get called? Do you have an example of your original ajax code?

Comment: Yes,  $('.modal-footer').show(); is called which is first line in OnSuccess

Comment: What does data.d[4].toLowerCase() equal? Can you console.log() (or whatever form of debugging you use) it?

Comment: Is there any JavaScript error in your console? Is it reached inside that `if` statement `if (data.d[4].toLowerCase().indexOf("success") >= 0) {` ? Put an `alert` there to make sure. Is that `url` path correct? There isn't enough information here for us to determine your code is working correctly.

Comment: Is the json you are generating manually valid? (manually generating json is almost always a bad idea.)

Comment: Why don't you trigger the mail in the password reset webmethod? And never send sensitive data via email - unless the mail is encrypted (PGP, S/MIME, ...)

Comment: `if` condition is passing

Comment: Where is your initial AJAX call code that is returning the `data.d[4]`, `data.d[3]`, etc. values?

Comment: Can you add the proper event methods to your second ajax call (success, error, etc) and see if they produce anything?

Comment: Request Payload is
`{mailTo:jit@gmail.com, reqName:imad md, username:imad, password:1234}` means it is right upto here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `WebMethod` attribute needs to be used with a **public** method:

**[How to: Use the WebMethod Attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx(v=vs.90).aspx)**

Change it to:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void SendMail(string mailTo, string reqName, string username, string password)
{
 //rest of code
```

You also need to use a `post` method to call the method as this is the default behaviour rather than a `get` method.

Comment: @imadoddin-ibn-alauddin No probs, it's easily done. You are also using a `get` request, I believe you need to use a `post` method too. :)

Comment: @hutchonoid - you are correct, ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods ONLY support `POST` requests and automatically JSON-encode their response, if any.

Comment: @KarlAnderson Thanks, I thought that was the case. I'll update the answer. :)